# Is possible to start a postgresql streaming replication using pg_dump instead of copying the database?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Hi i am able to start streaming replication with postgresql, copying the database files with doing theis command:

```
select pg_start_backup('clone', true);
```

That's right, but the thing is that i need to copy all the database files in /var/lib/postgresql/data to one server to another. That files are really big because of indexes for example.

I want to know if it is possible to do the same using a simple dump and restoring it on the slave, what is smaller and faster to transfer in the network, it will work? And what should i do to work?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you is there a fast way to start postgresql replication. I remember how fast is to do that with mysql, obvious that postgresql is far better (for unknow reason?) in speed for our application but....

Comment: Mysql has a lot of different types of replication so you are probably comparing apples to oranges. [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) is the easiest way, but yes, it will copy all the database files — there is no way round that for physical replication.

Comment: `pg_basebackup` is the way to go. Logically it is the same as `pg_dumpall` and will be much faster as the "import" step isn't necessary

Comment: dump restore is mostly slower than pg_basebackup when copying all databases in a cluster

Comment: Really? But the files are too big to transfer with the network (my brazilian provider wont helps) sometimes is fast to go to the slave using a CAR and a pendrive instead of stay waiting the transfer, now i am considering to migrate to postgresql 10 to be able to use logical replication, as compressed dumps are faster to go under the vpn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot start streaming replication without a physical copy of the data directory; usually created with the `pg_basebackup` command.

The reason for this has to do with what streaming replication and WAL shipping replication do. In both cases you are applying the Write Ahead Log to the data directory using postgresql's recovery mechanism. So in order to not break database consistency you must be applying the same change set to the same starting point and you are restricted to replicating the entire database cluster. This is also why you cannot interrupt streaming or drop WAL segments, since once you have broken continuity the database server cannot guarantee that it is in a consistent state.

In postgreSQL 10 or later you could use logical replication to replicate only one database in a cluster or even a single table. And in that case you can start with a "logical copy" of the database such as are produced by `pg_dump`.

Comment: The logical replication is exactly what i really need. When possible, we will migrate to PostgreSQL 10 and will stop the streaming replication in favor of logical replication.